# How to extract string (numbers) from txt file and convert to integers using regular expressions in python

Tags: python, string, int, extract

read through and parse a file with text and numbers.  extract all the         numbers in the file and compute the sum of the numbers. [txt file attached](http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/regex_sum_319771.txt)

This is for python 3 and above.

```
import re
names=open("regex_sum_319771_actual.txt")
numlist = list()
for files in names:
    files = files.rstrip()
    ext =re.findall('([0-9]+)',files)
    if len(ext)!= 1 :
        continue
    num = int(ext[0])
    numlist.append(num)
print('done',sum(numlist))


#the sum should give me an output ending with 689
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that will work :

```
import re


with open("regex_sum_319771_actual.txt", "r") as f:
    nums = re.findall(r'([0-9]+)', f.read())
    print(sum([int(i) for i in nums]))
```

**PS**: do not forget to close your file after reading if you do not use `with` statement

Comment: Thank you ! that was valuable , if you don't mind can you just tell what was fault in my code?

Comment: you need to pass the file once to regex then , you can loop over your regex list. and this `if len(ext)!= 1` will ignore if the ext has one matche like `['42']` so you end up summing only the list with more than one numbers in. and you get `79135`

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate char by char.

```
import re
names = open("regex_sum_319771_actual.txt", 'r')
nbr = []
for line in names:
    for carac in line:
       if re.match(r'\d', carac):
            nbr.append(int(carac))

print(sum(nbr))
names.close()
```

Comment: Wouldn't that make a number like 42 result in a sum of 6?

Comment: sorry, sum(nbr)

Comment: Well yeah, but OP wants "42" and "16" to sum to 58. Your solution would have `sum([4, 2, 1, 6])` which is 13.